# NSXMLParsing broken strings into an array using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

Using NSXMLParser, in the code below `conditionIconString = conditionIconString + string` stores the links into 1 big string, but I need it to store each link as a string in `[String]`.  I can't figure out how to do it?

```
var conditionsIcons = [String]()
var conditionIconString = String()
var weAreInsideAnItem = false

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {


            if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("icon-link") {
                weAreInsideAnItem = true

            }


        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("conditions-icon") {
            conditionsIcons = [String]()
            conditionsIcons = [""]
        }

 func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {


        if weAreInsideAnItem == true {
             if element.isEqualToString("icon-link") {
                    conditionIconString = conditionIconString + string
            }
        }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
       if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("icon-link") {
            conditionsIcons.append(conditionIconString)
            weAreInsideAnItem = false
       }
        elements.setObject(conditionsIcons, forKey: "conditionIcons")
}
```

This is the `XML` I'm parsing:  http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=39.557&lon=-79.3542&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml

```
<conditions-icon type="forecast-NWS" time-layout="k-p12h-n13-1">
<name>Conditions Icon</name>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/wind_sct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/DualImage.php?i=nra_sn&j=nsn&ip=20&jp=40
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/DualImage.php?i=sn&j=bkn&ip=20
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/nsct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/sct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/nsct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/sct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/nsct.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/bkn.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/nbkn.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/bkn.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/nshra40.png
</icon-link>
<icon-link>
http://forecast.weather.gov/newimages/medium/bkn.png
</icon-link>
</conditions-icon>
```

Comment: What does the XML look like?

Comment: @GregBrown I added it to my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `conditionIconString` is never reset, it grows with each `<icon-link>` tag that's found. Update the `didEndElement` functions to set this string back to empty before you start parsing the next element:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("icon-link") {
        conditionsIcons.append(conditionIconString)

        conditionIconString = String() // THIS IS THE KEY LINE

        weAreInsideAnItem = false
    }
    elements.setObject(conditionsIcons, forKey: "conditionIcons")
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  that line now saves the strings in an array, but it's adding xml String to an array in a loop like [first item, first item second item, first item, second item third item etc.]  do I need to move my conditionsIcons.append?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the follow up. You want to add each `item-link` to the `conditionIcons` array right?

Comment: Yes, and instead of adding each `item-link` to one array, my code is returning 15 arrays and each array is adding an `item-link`, again instead of just one array containing the 15 strings.  It's a little hard to put into words...

Comment: Do you modify `conditionsIcons` anywhere else. From the code you posted it should be working correctly.

Comment: I added in in my question a few lines in `didStartElement` where initialize `conditionsIcons` to create a place holder.  Could that be it?

Comment: The code you added looks okay to me. If `didEndElement` is the only place you call `append` I don't think it should be able to add anything other than the current `conditionIconString`. Do you call `append` elsewhere?

Comment: The problem was that line in didStartElement where I had empty'd out conditionsIcons...rather then letting the array build I was resetting it every time the parser reached a item-link.   I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to reset `conditionIconString` in `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:`. Add this before the line that says "weAreInsideAnItem = false":

```
conditionIconString = String()
```